# how do i get 5 random rows from a list

Tags: python, list, csv, random, rows

I'm pretty new to python, and my problem is, I'm trying to get 5 random rows from a list with a user input value condition, i get all the values from a chosen category and supposed to get only 5 rows from that randomly.

I've tried various solutions but it doesn't help me anyway
sry for my english

here's the code:

import csv
import random

```
with open("pontos.csv","r")as f:
    r=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    l=list(r)
    
    
    def ex1():
    #ex1
        for x in l:
            val=x[1],x[5]
            print(':'" ".join(val),"\n")
    

    def ex2():
        #ex2
        # escolhe cultura
            val = input("Cat:\n").split(",")

            for row in l:
                if all([x in row for x in val]):
                    print(','.join(row),"\n")
    
    def ex3():
        n=4
    # print("categorias:\n Desporto,cultura,História,Paisagem,Praia,Gastronomia,Natureza,Natureza")
        # escolhe cultura
        val = input("Cat:\n").split(",")
        for row in l:
                if all(x in row for x in val):
                    print(row)
                    
def main():
    while True:
        escolha=int(input("Menu:\n 1-mostrar todos os locais \n 2-Mostrar todos os locais de uma categoria \n 3- mostrar locais de uma categoria ao acaso \n 4-Sair \n Escolha: "))
        if escolha==1:
            ex1()
        if escolha ==2:
            ex2()
        if escolha==3:
            ex3()
            if escolha== 4:
                break
        else:
            print("escolha invalida")

main()
```

note: its on ex3

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample You could also shuffle and splice, but that would be less efficient. But not by much, as you have to have the full list first.

Comment: for the purpose of efficiency, it is best to avoid defining functions inside a loop (unless necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use random.sample for select a random row (item) from a list.
in main function your if escolha== 4: no effect because inside "if escolha==3:".

```
import csv
import random


with open("open_position.csv", "r") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    l = list(r)


def ex1():
    # ex1
    # used random.sample(list, number_sample)
    for x in random.sample(l, 5):
        val = x[1], x[5]
        print(':'" ".join(val), "\n")


def ex2():
    # ex2
    # escolhe cultura
    val = input("Cat:\n").split(",")

    # used random.sample(list, number_sample)
    for row in random.sample(l, 5):
        if all([x in row for x in val]):
            print(','.join(row), "\n")


def ex3():
    n = 4
    # print("categorias:\n Desporto,cultura,História,Paisagem,Praia,Gastronomia,Natureza,Natureza")
    # escolhe cultura
    val = input("Cat:\n").split(",")
    # used random.sample(list, number_sample)
    for row in random.sample(l, 5):
        if all(x in row for x in val):
            print(row)


def main():
    while True:
        escolha = int(input(
            "Menu:\n 1-mostrar todos os locais \n 2-Mostrar todos os locais de uma categoria \n 3- mostrar locais de uma categoria ao acaso \n 4-Sair \n Escolha: "))
        if escolha == 1:
            ex1()
        if escolha == 2:
            ex2()
        if escolha == 3:
            ex3()
            # this is incorrect
            # if escolha == 4:
            #     break
        if escolha == 4:
            break
        else:
            print("escolha invalida")


main()
```

Comment: yup that worked thanks, the if 4 was the indentation of the site 
thx